# while creating new ionic project in angular not generating module.ts and app-routing.module.ts files in the project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, module, generate

while creating ionic project with ionic start and followed by angular framework and choosing blank page, the app-routing.module.ts and app.module.ts file is missing. previously it does while creating a project and even when generating a page it separately create its own module.ts and routing.ts file. is there any solution back to normal?

this if the files created while creating a ionic project in angular framework[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8bcy.png)